# Flexbox layout - multiple lines if long enough

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have this layout with `flexbox`:

[image: Flexbox needed layout]

However, when the content in one of the columns of the first line increases, I don't get what I want. This next image explain what I get and what I want:

[image]

Basically, I want box 3 to span multiple lines, if needed, without changing the position of box4

Please help me into this. Thanks

Comment: Please post your code in a snippet and demonstrate an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You also have 2 repeated images with the desired placement, which is confusing.

Comment: I don't think it's confusing... I have the layout of image1. But when the contents of box3 increase, i get the layout in image2 (WHAT I GET). What I wanted was image3 (WHAT I WANT). Basically, I want box 3 to span multiple lines, if needed, without changing the position of box4. But I edited to be more clear.

Comment: I don’t think this is possible with flexbox.

Comment: It's not possible with Display flex. You should use available JQuery plugin for this.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me which plugins?? I don't know any

Answer (score 0):

**This thing is not possible using Flexbox**. You Should Use lots of Available JQuery plugins.

You can Check it out following JQuery plugins.

1.) [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/).

2.) [MCPants](http://mcpants.github.io/jquery.shapeshift/).

3.) [Gridster.](http://gridster.net/)

4.) [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

This are some of the available plugins which will give you, Your desirable output.
You can also find other plugins on search engine. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox doesn't work this way. It won't randomly fill out to use minimum height. The calculations required by your browser would slow everything down, if it is even possible to have the browser guess what you want precisely. You'll have to adjust your design I'm afraid.

Comment: I think you're right when you say it's not possible with flexbox, but I don't think the calculations would slow down the browser... Anyway I think I'll use JS to check for the extra height of the longest box and then just add margin-top: -(extraheight)px to box number 4. That would do it

Comment: They probably would a little, but the most important reason this is not possible is because you can think of a hundred different ways in which people would want a similar effect, but with slightly different conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox won't do what you need but you still can use them.

Here's what it would look like so below explanations will be easier to understand :

[image]

1. Create 2 containers that will display `inline-block`. The 1st (blue blocks) **is 75%**, the 2nd is **25%**.
2. **Blue blocks** are in a **flexbox**. Set the flex rules as you need it.
3. The **red block** has is own container, style it as you want too.

Based on the images you posted, blue blocks 1 and 2 are `flex: 1` and `flex: 2`, that means block 1 will always be 25% of its parent. This is why I set **25% to the red block container**.

---

**Check fiddle for full CSS :** https://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/dyxtq144/

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. The problem is that i want the last blue box to fill the width of the page if the the height of the red box is reduced, like so:
http://imgur.com/8O5YmoC

Comment: Ok I see, so it gets quite complicated, you may need to use `float` on the red box, but solution would be totally different from mine, sorry...